# Google cloud platform view request logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-talent-solution

I am new to Google Cloud platform, I am trying out Google's Talent Solution APIs and getting 400 and 409 errors. I would like to know how to see the error trace on my google cloud platform console for those requests? I could see those requests in the dashboard, not sure if I can drill down and see the exact error?

Comment: stackdriver logging is one source of all types of logs on GCP

Answer (score 1):

If you see these errors in your Developer Console main dashboard in the "Error Reporting" section, you should be able to click on the "Go to Error Reporting" link. There, you'll see a list of errors that happened lately. Clicking on one of them, you'll see more info on that specific error (occurrences, last seen, etc...) and a stack trace sample. Further down, you'll see a list of the last occurrences for that error and their respective link to the logs.

Alternatively, you may go directly to your Dev Console -> Logging section and choose the Talent Solution resource if available or the resource where you call the API from (App Engine, GKE, etc...) and filter the logs by error code to get details about these.